# Replace text in paragraph in div by clicking on a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to change a paragraph of text into different text by clicking on a fake 'link' (span) at the bottom of the page.

what I have thus far

```
<body>
  <p> here is a paragraph that i would like to change once the span below me is clicked </p> 
  <span id="click"> click me for the text above me to change </span>
  </center> 
</body>
<script>
  $( "click" ).click(function() {
    $( "p" ).replaceWith( "new paragraph" );
  });
</script>
```

I'm really new to jquery and javascript so any help would be appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** for id you should use  **#**

**2nd:** to get the previous element use `.prev()` .. `$(this).prev('p')`

```
<script>
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
    $(this).prev( "p" ).replaceWith( "<p>new paragraph</p>" );
});
</script>
```

> Note: id must be unique so don't use same id for more than one element
>   so try to use class instead   `<span class="click">` and then use `$('.click')` instead of `$('#click')`

**3rd:** what is `</center>` in your code should do?

**4th:** you should check to include jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**5th:** put script before closing body tag

full code

```
<body>
  <p> here is a paragraph that i would like to change once the span below me is clicked </p> 
  <span id="click"> click me for the text above me to change </span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(docuemt).ready(function(){
  $( "#click" ).click(function() {
    $(this).prev( "p" ).replaceWith( "<p>new paragraph</p>" );
  });
 });
</script>
</body>
```

to put img instead of paragraph  use

```
$(this).prev( "p" ).replaceWith('<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">');
```

to put img inside paragraph

```
$(this).prev( "p" ).html( 'new paragraph<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">' );
```

Comment: thank you! is it possible to put an img src inside a jquery string?

Comment: @JamieTheophilos what do you mean?? you want to put image instead of paragraph?? or put img inside a paragraph ??

Comment: putting an image inside a paragraph! how would you be able to position it then within that?

Comment: @JamieTheophilos Your're welcome .. Good Luck :) .. don't forget to upvote and accept my answer as well .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`$( "click" )`  should be `$( "#click" )`

Answer (score 0):

In reality you don't need `replaceWith()`. You can just use [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to change the text.

```
$( "#click" ).click(function() {
    $( "p" ).text( "new paragraph");
  });
```